# Terminal hangs when executing `docker exec` from google app engine SSH

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I am running a flex environment on google app engine which is hosting a Ruby on Rails application. I'd like to access the `rails console` on this application. When I SSH into an instance from my local terminal or through the google web console, I execute the command `docker exec -it gaeapp /bin/bash -c "bundle exec rails c"`

It starts to launch the rails console, but quickly hangs. I can get one or two commands in before it stops responding completely.

I am able to do as much as I like in the SSH console, but the second I run the `docker exec` command things start to hang. Any idea what is going on?

Our app.yaml

```
entrypoint: RAILS_ENV=develop bundle exec rails server --port $PORT
env: flex
runtime: ruby
instance_class: F1

env_variables:
  RAILS_MASTER_KEY: ${RAILS_MASTER_KEY}

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: [hidden]
```

Running 
`ruby '2.6.3'`
`'rails', '~> 5.2.3'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see in your app.yaml: `instance_class: F1`. This is NOT a valid setting for App Engine flexible.

So one possibility is that your instance is running out of resources. Please try to set more CPU and memory in [resource setting of app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/reference/app-yaml#resource-settings) for the instance.

Furthermore, be aware that if you are trying to make some changes using SSH inside of the instance, all of them will be lost when this particular instance will be killed/restarted and recreated from the original deployment code.

Comment: F1 is an instance class for scaling: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes

Comment: It is indeed an instance class, but only for the App Engine standard service, and that is not how the resources are defined in an App Engine flex service. You can check the resources a [F1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) machine has and specify them in your flex instance app.yaml.

Comment: Hi @theartofbeing did it work for you? If it did, please accept my answer for better visibility for another users. If no, please add your trace logs to the question to further investigate.